# How to use table in mdframed?

Tags: tables, mdframed

I am working on report format using `mdframed` and I need to add table inside `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15]
\textbf{Detailed Genotype Table}
\leavevmode
\newline
\begin{table}[ht]
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{center}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}c |P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|}
 \rowcolor{orange} Gene &SNP &Odds Ratio &Genotype &Genotype &Genotypic Effect &Citations &Frequency\\                              
  \hline
  1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\leavevmode
\newline
\end{mdframed}
\leavevmode
\newline
\end{document}
```

But in the above code i am not able to get table inside mdframed. May i know where i am wrong. Any example will help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: You can't put the frame around a floating object (the `{table}`) You can probably put it around the `{tabular}`+caption I would guess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not use the floating environment `table` inside `mdframed`; it doesn't make much sense to try to frame a floating object:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15]

\textbf{Detailed Genotype Table}

\centering
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}c |P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|}
 \rowcolor{orange} Gene &SNP &Odds Ratio &Genotype &Genotype &Genotypic Effect &Citations &Frequency\\                              
  \hline
  1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, however, you need the object to float, then you can invert the nesting order:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=orange,outerlinewidth=1, innerleftmargin=15, innertopmargin=15,innerbottommargin=15]
\centering
\textbf{Detailed Genotype Table}

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}c |P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|P{2cm} | P{2cm} | P{2cm}|}
 \rowcolor{orange} Gene &SNP &Odds Ratio &Genotype &Genotype &Genotypic Effect &Citations &Frequency\\                              
  \hline
  1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
  4 & -0.99 & -0.54 & 0.97 & -1.12 & 0.59 \\
  5 & -2.35 & -0.29 & -0.53 & 0.30 & -0.30 \\
  6 & -0.10 & 0.06 & -0.85 & 0.10 & -0.60 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{mdframed}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```