# How to color my (custom) lines/rules in a table contained by mdframed?

Tags: tables, color, rules, mdframed

As a follow up to [my recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123002/problem-with-custom-vertical-alignment-and-or-length-of-lines-rules-in-tabular-e): Now I'd like to put some color on to that line/rule. In the MWE below, `\arrayrulecolor{blue}\mycline{1-1}` throws an error (`undefined control sequence` with respect to `\arrayrulecolor`). How can I make `\mycline` accept a color?

```
% \PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}

 \newlength{\mycustomlength}
 \settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaa}

\makeatletter
\def\mycline#1{\expandafter\my@cline\@cline#1\@nil}

\def\my@cline#1\leaders#2\hfill{%
#1\hfill\leaders#2\hskip\mycustomlength\hfill\kern\z@}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor=RGB,table]{mdframed}

% \usepackage[RGB]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,111,222}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip, nobreak=true, innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, frametitleaboveskip=3pt, frametitlebelowskip=2pt, skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\mdfdefinestyle{my_style}{%
     linecolor=mycolor,middlelinewidth=0.7pt, frametitlebackgroundcolor=mycolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}

%------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style,frametitle=\color{white}{OOO}]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{|p{\mycustomlength}|}*{1}{X}@{}}

\textbf{AAAAAA} & \\
\mycline{1-1}
%%%\arrayrulecolor{blue}\mycline{1-1}
% \cline{1-1}
aaaaaaaaa & \textbf{aaaa} \\
aaaa & \textbf{aa} \\
\\
\textbf{BBBB} & \\
% \rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}
% & \\
% \\
% \cline{1-1}
\mycline{1-1}
bbb & bbbbbbbbb \textbf{b} \\
bbbbb & \textbf{B} \\


\end{tabularx}
% \end{tabulary}

\end{mdframed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Cf. also:

- [Clash among packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52973/clash-among-packages) and
- [How to use table in mdframed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50543/how-to-use-table-in-mdframed)

Note that *in theory* `mdframed` should load `xcolor` which in turn should load `colortbl` *(cf. the resp. documentation files)*. But there seem multiple ways of calling these packages; and apart from *how* they are called/loaded the order in which they are called/loaded also matters...

Comment: The correct loading order is: `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor={RGB,table}]{mdframed}` -- You forgot the brackets at `xcolor={RGB,table}`

Comment: yeah, wasn't sure about that (found no working example) ...

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Can you reconcile that line with David's MWE ? *I tried - but have yet to succeed.*

Comment: At the moment I have no TeX and I can't test anything.

Comment: Found the issue -- the package `tikz` loads `xcolor` and so all options related to `xcolor` are ignored.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Hmm, sure? Cuz the `RGB` option does *not* seem to be ignored... or is it?

Comment: It is. The package tikz.sty loads `pgfcore.sty` which loads `xcolor`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I can accept that `tikz` loads `xcolor`, but does it load `xcolor` *with* `xcolor`'s **`RGB` option** - or *without* it?

Comment: Answered in chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MWE generates an unknown option error for mdfamed with the version I have, so I removed that and loaded `colortbl` which otherwise wasn't loaded. Since `colortbl` redefines `\cline` The patch in the previous answer didn't match and you need a modified one.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}

\usepackage{colortbl}
 \newlength{\mycustomlength}
 \settowidth\mycustomlength{blaaaaaaaa}

\makeatletter
\def\mycline#1{\expandafter\my@cline\@cline#1\@nil}



\def\my@cline#1\@multispan\@ne#2{%
#1\@multispan\@ne
{\CT@arc@\hfill\leaders\hrule\@height\arrayrulewidth\hskip\mycustomlength\hfill\kern\z@}}%


\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor=RGB]{mdframed}

% \usepackage[RGB]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,111,222}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip, nobreak=true, innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip, innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip, frametitleaboveskip=3pt, frametitlebelowskip=2pt, skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}

\mdfdefinestyle{my_style}{%
     linecolor=mycolor,middlelinewidth=0.7pt, frametitlebackgroundcolor=mycolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}

%------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{mdframed}[style=my_style,frametitle=\color{white}{OOO}]

\arrayrulecolor{blue}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{|p{\mycustomlength}|}*{1}{X}@{}}

\textbf{AAAAAA} & \\
\mycline{1-1}
%%%\arrayrulecolor{blue}\mycline{1-1}
% \cline{1-1}
aaaaaaaaa & \textbf{aaaa} \\
aaaa & \textbf{aa} \\
\\
\textbf{BBBB} & \\
% \rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}
% & \\
% \\
% \cline{1-1}
\mycline{1-1}
bbb & bbbbbbbbb \textbf{b} \\
bbbbb & \textbf{B} \\


\end{tabularx}
% \end{tabulary}

\end{mdframed}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You've earned yourself the `Saviour` badge.

Comment: How can this be reconciled with Marco's comment, above? Using the one-liner of `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor={RGB,table}]{mdframed}` ? *Note the added curly braces.*

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Marco's comment is same as mine. You had an undefined mdffamed option table, you need to fix that and load colortbl, I just removed it and loaded colortbl and he fixed it so the option is passed to xcolor which then loads colortbl. Moral is, don't ignore error messages.

Comment: Sorry for opening this question up again, but it doesn't actually help with my problem (yet): See the MWE posted here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5855584/ (*uncommented* `\rule{\mycustomlength}{0.4pt}` and got rid of the corresponding `\mycline{1-1}` in that line). I want the length of `\rule` (as it appears in that MWE), ***not*** of `\mycline` (as it appears in that MWE). Notice that, in contrast to `\myrule`, `\rule` does ***not*** touch the borders of the `tabular` column. This is the behaviour I want: **no** "touch". How to correct?

Comment: [Your previous answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123012/27721) to my previous already *did* feature the "no-touch" feature... (cf. [*this* MWE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5855619/)) - So I guess it's just yet another minor change needed... but which?

Comment: oops `\@ne` appears twice in the original code so patch was in wrong place: fixed.

Comment: Removing the | unfortunately rocks the boat and introduces a ~2mm shift to the right of those (difficult) lines: How to make your solution neat again for `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{1}{p{\mycustomlength}}*{1}{X}@{}}` (*without* `|p`...) ?

Comment: you need to add space either side of the leaders to match the inter column material, usually,`\hpace{\arrayrulewidth}` or `\hspace{\tabcolsep` or both.

Answer (score 2):

To understand the error related to `mdframed` I want to provide a small answer.

Options are separated by commas, so your input

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor=RGB,table]{mdframed}
```

is passing the options to `mdframed`:

1. `framemethod=TikZ` == known
2. `xcolor=RGB` == known
3. `table`== unknown

If you want to pass a value to an option which contains a comma, you have to embrace it. So the correct syntax is:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ, xcolor={RGB,table}]{mdframed}
```

Now you are passing two options to `mdframed`.

---

But why does it have no effect? I decided to implement the option `xcolor` in the following way: If the package `xcolor` is already loaded, ignore all options. The package TikZ loads `xcolor` and so the options of `xcolor` are ignored. To add options to `xcolor` you can do the following:

1. Load `xcolor` separately

   ```
   \usepackage[table,RGB]{xcolor}
   \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
   ```
2. Pass options to `xcolor` via `\PassOptionsToPackage`

   ```
   \PassOptionsToPackage{table,RGB}{xcolor}
   \usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
   ```
3. Change the order of the options:

   ```
    \usepackage[xcolor={RGB,table},framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
   ```

I recommend the first method.